# Maintain whitelist of Rails routes for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing, controllers

In a Ruby Rails project, I have an array of strings matching the controller/action syntax used by the Rails routing protocols. These are my public routes, requiring no authentication. I want to compare the list to the current `controller#action` in order to enforce login authentication.

The problem: I cannot figure out exactly how Rails parses a routing string and determines the appropriate `controller#action`. I need to replicate this functionality for the comparison, but Rails core code is quite soupy, and I haven't been able to pinpoint the logic.

To put it in terms of pseudo-code, here's a sample of my whitelist array in YAML syntax, coming out of a config file...

```
public_routes: [
  'public',
  'auth/sessions#new',
  'auth/sessions#create',
  'admin#login'
]
```

Then in my `ApplicationController`...

```
before_filter :check_authentication!

...

def check_authentication!
  Settings.public_routes.each do |this_route|
    # parse string this_route into a namespace::controller#action
    return if [current route matches parsed route]
  end
  # enforce authentication procedures here
end
```

I already have logic to allow all actions on the `PublicController` (line 1 of `public_routes` array). Matching the other three is where I am getting tripped up.

P.S. The login enforcement is happening globally within `ApplicationController` in order to DRY out my controllers, and to centralize my whitelist of publicly permissible routes. I *could* do it inside each controller, but that's not the goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can get back the current namespace, controller and action value from the params, like params[:controller], so inside your comparison loop, just make up the url. Or you can get back the request url with request.fullpath method.

Comment: This looks promising, any idea where I can find a list of the values included in `params` by default?

Comment: i used to use this gem https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print to inspect the value of any variable.